# Performance Evaluation of Linux Scheduler

Tags: linux, performance, benchmarking, evaluation, scheduler

I have done some simple changes to the scheduler in the Linux Kernel. Now, I would
like to see how those changes affect the response time of the system; in other words, 
I would like to know how long a context switch takes with my modifications compared to the original scheduler. A straightforward approach would be to use the time stamp counter, and use then the printk to output the time it took for the context switch; obviously, in this case a lot of information is printed out. So I wonder if there is any other, better approach to measure the Linux scheduler response time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several kernel-level trace frameworks, which might help you. See the [Kernel Trace Systems](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Trace_Systems) page on [eLinux.org](http://eLinux.org) for a nice overview of the available options.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into this!